# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 20, 100, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement CNN and keras to predict DNA sequence binding sites(TFBS). i convert x (train) and y (test) to one-hot encoding and then enter to CNN model. But when I am running the *model.fit* it is giving this error.

> > ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 20, 100, 1))

and here is my code :

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Activation, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf


# load data
with open("D:\رسالة الماجستير\database new\PromoterSeq.csv") as csvDataFile2:
    r = csv.reader(csvDataFile2)
    promoter = []
    for row in r:
        promoter.append(row[1])
        #print(promoter)

dataset=[]   
for i in range(1,11):
    t = promoter[i]    
    dataset.extend(t)

# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
x , y = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.5)
#print("training data are :\n",x)
#print("\n")
#print("test data are :\n",y)

#**************************************************************
# one-hot encoding for X
alphabet = 'acgt'
# define a mapping of chars to integers
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
# integer encode input data
integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in x]
#print(integer_encoded)
# one hot encode
onehot = list()
for value in integer_encoded:
    letter = [0 for _ in range(len(alphabet))]
    letter[value] = 1
    onehot.extend(letter)

x = np.array(onehot)
x = x.reshape(1,20,100,1) 
#print(x)

#**************************************************************
# one-hot encoding for Y
alphabet = 'acgt'
# define a mapping of chars to integers
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
# integer encode input data
integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in y]
#print(integer_encoded)
# one hot encode
oneh = list()
for value in integer_encoded:
    letter = [0 for _ in range(len(alphabet))]
    letter[value] = 1
    oneh.extend(letter)

y = np.array(oneh)
y = y.reshape(1,20,100,1) 
#print(y.shape)

#**************************************************************
# define the CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(20,100,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, verbose=0, batch_size=12)
```

Comment: Firstly: welcome! Can you simplify your question, it would be easier for others to reproduce your code and see where the issues are. This can be done for example by providing dummy data as input data and not requiring to load a csv that only you have access to. Additionally, you could simplify further your code to highlight what the actual problems are, for example you could simify the network architecture as it seems to be not an issue here.

Comment: Your model is primed to predict a binary output (`Dense(1)`) however the shape of your labels says otherwise (`y.reshape(1,20,100,1)`)

Comment: please, how i change this step??